# How to dispatch a double click event on an element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I can dispatch a simple click event (without any optional parameters) with:

```
var clickEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
clickEvt.initEvent("click");
element.dispatchEvent(clickEvt);
```

But how do I dispatch a double-click event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just substitute `"click"` with `"dblclick"` in `clickEvt.initEvent`:

```
var dblclickEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
dblclickEvt.initEvent("dblclick");
element.dispatchEvent(dblclickEvt);
```

Comment: isn't initEvent depprecated?

Comment: @Snedden27 No idea, if you have a better answer, I'd be happy if you posted it.

Answer (score 3):

The feauture used in the accepted answer (`Event.initEvent()`) has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent/).

Instead, use specific event consructors like [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

So to answer your question, it would be something like :

```
var doubleClickEvent = new Event('dblclick');      //define double click event

element.dispatchEvent(doubleClickEvent);           //trigger double click even
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked in Chrome@83

```
const event = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  view: window
});

const buttonEl = document.querySelector('#my-button');
buttonEl.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Best solution compared the others. Thanks!